# Помогите решить проблему с DateFormat в  AndroidStudio

Tags: android, java, android-studio

На рабочем компьютере пишу проект  в  AndroidStudio и там он работает хорошо, решил импортировать  в  AndroidStudio на домашний комп и столкнулся с проблемой в `DateFormat`
этот метод переводит дату, типа "4 Декабря 2014 17:03" в long, типа 140764890000.
Вот на работе он это делает на ура, а дома пишет :

> W/System.err﹕
> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable
> date: "4 Декабря 2014 17:03" (at
> offset 2)  W/System.err﹕ at
> java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)

```
public long dateToLong(){
    Date df;
    try {
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm", myDateFormatSymbols).parse(mDate);
        datetolong = df.getTime();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(MyLog.LOG_TAG, " Formated Date " + datetolong);

    return datetolong;
}

private static DateFormatSymbols myDateFormatSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols() {

    @Override
    public String[] getMonths() {
        return new String[]{"Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня",
                "Июля", "Августа", "Сентября", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря"};
    }

};
```

**Обновление**

Обратил внимание на следующее: на андройде ниже 4.2 работает, а вот начиная с 4.2 нет и даже на рабочем. Ещё, что касается 4.2, если смотреть в сам `DateFormate` class, то имеются проблемы с импортом следующих библиотек

```
import libcore.icu.ICU;
import libcore.icu.LocaleData;
```

Comment: Проверьте локаль на домашнем компе

Comment: @Mage

Прошу прощения, а можно чуть конкретнее

Comment: Попробуйте вместо myDateFormatSymbols передавать нужную локаль. Например new Locale("ru"). Подозреваю, что вместо, например, Октября будет использовано Окт. Не проверял.

Comment: обратил внимание на следующее: на андройде ниже 4.2 работает, а вот начиная с 4.2 нет и даже на рабочем. Ещё, что касается 4.2, если смотреть в сам DateFormate class то имеются проблемы с импортом следующих библиотек 

import libcore.icu.ICU;
import libcore.icu.LocaleData;

Comment: @smilemakc видать, что-то устарело

Comment: @smackmychi

Борюсь уже какой день... может, подскажете, как мне строку 4 Декабря 2014 17:03 перевести в long  типа  Date?

Comment: @smackmychi

Спасибо Вам большое, Ваш метод работает (но вот непонятным остаётся обозначение месяца в SimpleDateFormate "MMMMMMMM" не встречал такого патерна).

Ещё я нашёл и свой способ реализации))) переводил название месяца в цифру, т.е. в номер месяца, и тоже работало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy HH:mm", new Locale("ru"));
    format.setDateFormatSymbols(myDateFormatSymbols);
    Date df = format.parse("4 Декабря 2014 17:03");
    System.out.println(df.getTime());
    System.out.println(format.format(df));
```

[[@smilemakc](/users/23981/smilemakc)](/users/23981/smilemakc) [документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Найдете там таблицу с примерами и все увидите. Где M/MM - подставляется число. Где MMM - сокращение. и т.д. Я не разбирался, мб и MMMM подойдет.

UPD: и MMMM подходит

Comment: @smackmychi 
Хочу заметить, что в данном примере лишнее setDateFormateSymbols
без него работает хорошо, с ним таже проблема!

Comment: @smilemakc странно, у меня и так, и сяк работает. Мой вариант дает возможность выводить названия месяцев именно с большой буквы. Хотя это тоже под вопросом))))

Comment: @smackmychi
Вот такой вот парадокс. В Android-Studio ситуация следующая:
Если применять setDateFormatSymbols перед парсингом строки, то `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:`
Если применять после парсинга, то обратное преобразование в строку даёт название месяца на английском.
Если не применять вообще, то месяц на русском, но с маленькой буквы.

Comment: @smilemakc вообщем, в любом случае можно как-то выкрутиться)))

Comment: @smackmychi
Конечно, можно, учитывая то, что глапвное для меня в данной ситуации получить long))))

А Вам ещё раз спасибо за внимание!

Comment: @smilemakc, пожалуйста